# Child div with minus position is cutting

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

There is child container with `position:absolute`, and when I set its right `position` in minus, it's not going out of container and cutting the external part of it. I also check it with `z-index` but it's not working.

Here is a JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/shahidbasheer/az6uxywx/10/

```
// Parent element
.logign-form-wraper {
   margin: 5% auto;
   max-width: 466px;
   overflow-x: hidden;
   padding: 20px;
}

// child element
.mistake_notify {
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    right: 0;
    margin-right: -200px;
    max-width: 320px;
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I totally understand your question.  If you're asking why it's disappearing as it moves out of the boundaries of its parent div, it's because you have `overflow-x: hidden;` set on `.logign-form-wraper`

Comment: Yes working thanks jordan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `overflow-x:hidden` from `.logign-form-wraper`.

Also remove `margin-right:-200px` and give `-200px` or other value you wish to `right` instead of `0` because you are using `position:absolute` in that div.